# How do you set the worldCopyJump option in shiny / leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am using shiny and leaflet from R to display  a map in a webpage. How do I set the worldCopyJump option? Here's a brief sketch of what I have:

```
shinyUI(
//// stuff...
        leafletOutput("mymap")
//// stuff...
)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

               leaflet() %>%      
                  addTiles() %>%
                  //// stuff...
     })
})
```